# Simple way to check google username and password in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, authentication, web-services

What is the simple way to check google username and password whether it is correct in iphone app?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958188/how-do-i-authenticate-a-google-user-on-the-iphone-using-gdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the direct answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471898/google-app-engine-with-clientlogin-interface-for-objective-c).
Use the first part of the answer is enough for you. Check for the "SID" returned by the dictionary in the result.