# User Login to iOS application using Google id

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication

I'm struggling to find any information about logging a user into an iOS application using their google id/password. Can anyone point me towards any documentation or resources?

Comment: Is that what you mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958188/how-do-i-authenticate-a-google-user-on-the-iphone-using-gdata